# jQuery li with an id of number won't add addClass

Tags: jquery

I've been banging my head on this for hours and can't figure out why this won't work. I've got two li's with id's of 1_userType and 2_userType.

```
<ul>
    <li id="1_userType">User Type 1</li>
    <li id="2_userType">User Type 2</li>
</ul>
```

I have a ternary that says if a value is true remove a class of muted and if it is false it will add a class of muted.

```
val === true ? $('ul li#1_userType, ul li#2_userType').removeClass('muted') : $('ul li#1_userType, ul li#2_userType').addClass('muted');
```

Except this doesn't add or remove the class no matter if it returns true or false. The strange thing is I can add a console.log('true') or console.log('false') in the ternary and it hits one or the other. This isn't making sense to me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [I can't replicate this behaviour.](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/8wNU8/2/)

Comment: true will **always** evaluate to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just want to do ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch)):

```
$('#1_userType, #2_userType').toggleClass('muted', val === true);
```

Adding the `ul li` in there is unnecessary since lookups by IDs (which should be unique in a document) can be done via the native getElementById method. Also, [valid element IDs - before HTML5 - should not begin with numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), although I don't think that's why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i think that Ids cant start with a number.